# Number of bitcoins mined algorithm

Tags: money-supply, library, libbitcoin

Is there a library to know the number of bitcoin mined at a given block number ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fixed rate for how many bitcoins are mined each block. The block reward halves every 210,000 blocks, see [Controlled Supply](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Controlled_supply).

Here is a short term bitcoin distribution projection from the [Bitcoin Wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnN8S.png):

[image]

To calculate the total coins for a given block, try:

`coins.py`

```
block = 210000 * 10
totalCoins = 0

subsidy = 50.0
for i in range(1,block):
    if(i%210000 == 0):
        subsidy = subsidy / 2
    totalCoins += subsidy
    #print i, subsidy, totalCoins

print totalCoins
```

Also, you might find this helpful: [Deflation Calculator](https://github.com/JBaczuk/altcoin_deflation_calculator/blob/master/plot.py)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm looking for the (pseudo) code that would generate this array.

Comment: Just added some code and a project that might be helpful